# Turn a list of strings into an `IntFlag`

Tags: python, enums

I have a bunch of `IntFlag` types, and I expect to frequently convert lists of strings from config files into members of those types. My current plan is to extend `IntFlag`:

```
class BetterIntFlag(IntFlag):
    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, items):
        value = cls(0)
        for item in items:
            value |= cls[item]
        return value
```

I'm satisfied with this solution, but I can't help but feel that I must be missing a concise built-in way to do this.

I'm on 3.3 with backported enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by backport you mean `aenum`<sup>1</sup>, it's built-in:

```
from aenum import IntFlag

class Color(IntFlag):
  red = 1
  green = 2
  blue = 4
```

and in use:

```
--> Color['red|blue']
<Color.blue|red: 5>

--> items = ['red', 'blue']
--> Color['|'.join(items)]
<Color.blue|red: 5>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Alas, I'm using `enum.py` from Python 3.6.5, which does not support that.

Comment: In any case, given that you've made this suggestion, it seems safe to say that there's no built-in functionality for this in stdlib.

Comment: @ThomSmith:  You could blur the lines between names and values and define your own `_missing_` to handle calls like `Color('red blue')` (or however you wanted your strings).